# Error when tyring to install mysql-python

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I am tearing my hair on my head trying to install `mysql-python` via `pip install mysql-python`, and I end up with the following error. The project is using Python 2.7, therefore I cannot upgrade to Python 3. I have come across similar errors via internet, but still none of the solutions works for me. Any ideas ?

```
Collecting mysql-python
      Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
      Building wheel for mysql-python (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/loglab/serv2/.venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-4fxq3r
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/
      Complete output (30 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
      copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
      running build_ext
      building '_mysql' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-1x6jhf/python2.7-2.7.18~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
      _mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: Python.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
         29 | #include "Python.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysql-python
      Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
    Failed to build mysql-python
    Installing collected packages: mysql-python
        Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /home/loglab/serv2/.venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_uts6b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/loglab/serv2/.venv/include/site/python2.7/mysql-python
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/
        Complete output (30 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
        copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
        running build_ext
        building '_mysql' extension
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
        x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-1x6jhf/python2.7-2.7.18~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
        _mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: Python.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
           29 | #include "Python.h"
              |          ^~~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/loglab/serv2/.venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wIIhMj/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_uts6b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/loglab/serv2/.venv/include/site/python2.7/mysql-python Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: which distro are you using?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by distribution?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?  Do you happen to have the python-devel package installed?   I don't read Cyric(?) so I'm assuming that the Cyric is pointing out that it can't find Python.h  (as I've encountered something like that before).

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)